# How do I know when a render array will be processed properly?

Tags: forms, theming

I'm still getting to grips with render arrays and there similarity to FAPI arrays is a point of confusion. I'm customizing a node form using `hook_form_alter` and I wanted to insert some custom markup in place of a field.

I have inserted a table render array as a child of a the field FAPI container array and much to my surprise the table was rendered. What's going on here?

How do I know when a render array will be processed properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Render Arrays in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/930760)

> Note: While render arrays and arrays used by the Form API share
>   elements, properties and structure, many properties on form elements
>   only have meaning for the Form API, not for the Render API. Form API
>   arrays are transformed into Render arrays by drupal_get_form.

Because form arrays are converted to render arrays before they are rendered if you add a render array to the form array it will be also rendered when the whole form-array-converted-to-render-array is processed.

As the quoted text says you have to keep in mind that form arrays are not directly renderable, they have to be converted first to a render array. During this conversion, render array attached to the form array are bypassed because they are already a render array.